# Why aren't the functions getting called in this basic Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
package com.basicspring.basicapp;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class Config {

@Bean
public Dependency dependency(){
    System.out.println("In dependency");
    return new Dependency();
}

@Bean
public DependencyContainer dependencyContainer(){
  System.out.println("In dependencyContainer");
   dependency();
   dependency();
   dependency();
   return new DependencyContainer(dependency());
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify: none and -no verify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

22:00:36.567 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7276c8cd

22:00:36.601 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'

22:00:36.759 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor'

22:00:36.762 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'

22:00:36.765 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'

22:00:36.766 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'

22:00:36.778 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'config'

22:00:36.798 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'dependency'

In dependency

22:00:36.820 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'dependencyContainer'

In dependencyContainer

22:00:36.833 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in PropertySource 'systemProperties' with value of type String



Process finished with exit code 0
```

Please look at the statements "In dependency" and "In dependencyContainer" in the output. Even after manually calling the dependency() method twice in dependencyContainer() method, it's not getting executed twice.

Comment: because default scope is singleton, so it gets dependency once.

Comment: Did you import Dependency class? BTW your naming convention is terrible.

Comment: hey thanks, I understood what you've said but I still have trouble understanding what happened to my manually called functions

Comment: @MiroslavTrninic hey thanks for the reply, all the other classes are in the same package which are public

Comment: Note: to do something "thrice" means to do it three times, not two times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default scope of a spring bean is singleton. Meaning there is only a single instance of a bean that is used throughout the application. If you use the @Configuration, calls to methods annotated with @Bean get routed to check if there is already an instance of the bean. If an instance is present that instance is returned without executing the function. If you remove the @Configuration annotation all the three calls get executed.

Comment: Or remove @Bean on dependency then it is regular method and it will be called multiple times